# Angular help for showing data from API

Tags: angularjs, json

Given the following JSON files:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byt0rakzaB6bNXM0RW1ua3owY1U/view?usp=sharing 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byt0rakzaB6bdEhCSmFnZDBuZlU/view?usp=sharing

Create a responsive web page to display the data provided above.
Requirements:
The page is responsive on all mobile devices
Utilize Angular JS 1.X as the structure framework

That was the question . I have Coded like following to make them like the screenshot table[image: Requirement screenshot]. Data is showing in console. I can show the data in table like the required screenshot
.....................................................

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("NHL_Goaltenders.json")
    .then(function(response) {
       $scope.myData1 = response;
       console.log(response);
      $http.get("NHL_Skaters.json").then(function(response){
         $scope.myData2 = response;
        console.log(response);
      });
    });
});
</script> 


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
  <!-- <div ng-repeat="x in myData1">
    <p>{{ x.firstname}}</p> -->
<table border="1">

   <tr>

     <td>NAME</td>&nbsp;
     <td>TEAM</td>&nbsp;
     <td>GP</td>&nbsp;
     <td>G</td>&nbsp;
     <td>A</td>&nbsp;
     <td>PTS</td>&nbsp;
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="x in myData1">

     <td>{{ x.Headers[0]}}</td>&nbsp;
     <td>{{ x.Headers[1]}}</td>&nbsp;
     <td>{{ x.Headers[2]}}</td>&nbsp;
     <td>{{ x.Headers[3]}}</td>&nbsp;
     <td>{{ x.Headers[4]}}</td>&nbsp;
     <td>{{ x.Headers[5]}}</td>&nbsp;
  </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in myData1">

     <td>{{ x.Statistics[0][0]}}</td>&nbsp;
     <td>{{ x.Statistics[0]}}</td>&nbsp;
     <td>{{ x.Statistics[2]}}</td>&nbsp;
     <td>{{ x.Statistics[3]}}</td>&nbsp;
     <td>{{ x.Statistics[4]}}</td>&nbsp;
     <td>{{ x.Statistics[5]}}</td>&nbsp;
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: FYI, you probably mean `$scope.myData1 = response.data` and `$scope.myData2 = response.data`. The promise returned by the `$http` service resolves requests with a **response** object, not the parsed response body. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the possible solutions: https://plnkr.co/edit/VahUhdPGF0BQAai9Lwl8?p=preview

```
  <table border="1">
     <tr>
       <th ng-repeat="header in goaltenders.Headers">{{header}}</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="row in goaltenders.Statistics track by $index">
       <td ng-repeat="item in row track by $index">{{ item }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks cloudy.one. I Just want to make some modification and dd bootstrap classes to make it responsive. The table will be in a slider. Do you have any suggestion for that ? Thanks in advance